# What can cause RewriteRule to work only for certain pages?

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

Are there any external factors (that is, not in the `.htaccess` file) that can cause the `RewriteRule` not to work for specific URLs (of existing pages)?

I have the following code in the `.htaccess` file (it performs redirection but not for all URLs):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

[Edit]
I've already made some changes since I first posted the question, changes that didn't bring any improvement with regards to the way redirections are made - so the problem still needs a solution.

The whole `.htaccess` file content is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(xml|txt)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, public, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</ifModule>

FileETag None    

<ifModule mod_headers.c>    
  Header unset Last-Modified
</ifModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule .? http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

**Old Answer**

.htaccess rewrites work from the top down. Once a re-write match has been found then apache stops there. So you need to put your re-direction first like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php

</IfModule>
```

---

**New Answer**

instead of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule .? http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

try:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?domain\.com/ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or if that doesn't work try:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?domain\.com(.+)? [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, @Emmanuel . As strange as this may sound, doing what you suggested doesn't help me see all the pages on other domains being redirected. [Here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12005/rewriterule-not-working-for-certain-urls) you can see more about the URLs that are'n directed and other ways I've tried to make this work. After days and days of trying to solve this I tend to believe the error hides somewhere else.

Comment: @keikki - Mm... okay, how about trying this for the redirect: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: @Emmanuel , I've tried `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC] and RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]` and the result was: "The page isn't redirecting properly" - on the one hand; on the other hand, correct me if I'm wrong, but how would additional domains be redirected towards the main one if the `^www\.example\.com ` isn't negated with "!" ? Yes, it is a good idea to make the URLs not to be case sensitive, but this doesn't address the problem I confront now: domain forwarding with the strange behavior of working only on certain URLs. Thanks again for trying, though!

Comment: @keiki - Mmm... okay I think the `!^(www\.)?` in your rewrite is a conditional for matching a url with or without the `www`. Could you post some of the urls that aren't being redirected? And is the code you've got above all of your .htaccess file?

Comment: @Emmanuel , URLs with or without www are matched by (www\.)?, while the "bang" (!) negates the whole URL, because I wanted every URL with the %{HTTP_HOST} different of "domain", to be redirected. An URL that isn't redirected is www.anotherDomain.com/existentDirectory/. I'll gladly edit my post to add all the .htaccess file.

Comment: @keiki - Okay I've totally edited my above answer, so try it now and see if it works